# Why I can't get Lookup Column ID from Source List by Flow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, flow

I have a question about Flow for Sharepoint List. I have 2 Lists, and one of them has a lookup column to another.
List 1: Currency List (Target List)
[image]

List 2: Price Table (Source List). I want to get a Value of Ask Rate (Lookup Column) to ExRate Column (Number Column) to use in Price (Caculated Column).
[image]

My Flow:
[image]

Anyone know what happens, please help me!

And another question: If I don't have ExRate, I want to use an expression to calculate in the Price Column, please give me the expression?

Comment: Do you have added lookup column in Currency List and you are referencing this lookup from Price Table? correct me if I am wrong. can you add screenshot of your lookup column's configuration settings as well?

Comment: Can you explain the question? You are saying the ID is missing but they are not the same ID it has to be like that. Technically you need to use "get Items" not "Get Item" then filter the values based on column name and value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, everyone, especially @jerry_MSFT, you always help me in difficult times.
Based on your suggestions, I check my Lookup Column Setting and realize something new:
When I choose: The Lookup Column Title **(linked to the item)**. The Flow can't get the ID of the Lookup item.
[image]

But when I choose: The Lookup Column Title, It works fine.

Comment: Glad to see you figure it out. That's the common mistake everyone will have :-) Hope you go smoothly with your future tasks. BTW, please mark the reply as answer  so other community members can avoid this small trap.

Comment: I want to ask you a general question, can we use Flow instead of Additional Lookup column? I see this way will help us have the right to affect the columns more easily such as using calculate or lookup from another table, how do you feel, give me your suggestion.

Comment: It is possible to do so. You will need to do a bit more work with flow/workflow to find the right item in the target list. For you situation, you will need to write some code with the filter or query. As I assume you will need to handle a bunch of similar currency rate data with like USD to Euro and USD to JPY.

Comment: And for I am not an expert on Flow, usually i change the plan case by case. You can open a thread on the flow forum https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Flow-Community/ct-p/FlowCommunity. There are many veterans who can give you more help.

Comment: @jerry. In this example, my final purpose is to calculate the Price Field. If we don't have ExRate Field to get value from Lookup Field. Can we use Formula or Expression to Calculated directly?

Comment: If the exrate field is not in the list, then you will NOT be able to get the value via Formula expression. Still you will need use a lookup/flow to get the correct rate value from another list.

Answer (score 1):

Tan, It seems you have some trouble with the flow i set. I recreated a new set of lists and the flow shows look up column ID properly. Please double check the lookup column setting. And you can add a get item action to get more properties of the newly created item. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks, @jerry_MSFT. You are the real friend saved me.